# Unable to close questions as duplicate: "an error has occurred; please try again"

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, close-dialog, ipad, safari

I have been getting this for weeks when trying to close a question as duplicate. This happens on both OS X with Safari and on my iPad (3rd gen) in Safari. I also tried Chrome, same issue. I have been unable to close questions as duplicate for weeks.

[image]

Is there any way to diagnose/resolve this on my end, is it perhaps tied to my user account somehow? Or is this a (known) bug?

**UPDATE:**

Recently I see this code directly above the red error box after entering some text in the text field:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> <html> </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried closing using the full version of the site?  Or just the mobile version?

Comment: You can use e.g. the developer tools or firebug (no idea if safari has something similar) to view the actual response from the AJAX request the site sends.

Comment: Yes, I tried Safari and Chrome on OS X.

Comment: it is working again...